# What is the difference between these two ways of changing a functions prototype in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In the following code a constructor function, an object instance, and two examples of changing a functions prototype. What is the difference between these two methods? As far as I can work out the second method will update the object instance even if it is after the declaration of that instance, whereas the other will not. Is this the only difference?

```
function Foo(name, color) {
  this.name = name;
  this.color = color;
}

var bar = new Foo('name', 'color');
```

First method:

```
Foo.prototype = {age: 6};
```

Second method:

```
Foo.prototype.age = 4;`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Foo.prototype = {age: 6};
```

First method is going to override  constructor and ____proto____ link ,if you were using inheritance not a good approach becuase you will destroy the proto links and prototype chain

Its better to use

```
Foo.prototype.age = 4;`
```

In this way you are just only adding a property all the prototype chains will remail intact

Comment: Would you only use `Foo.prototype = {age: 6};` specifically to override the inheritance chain?

Comment: If you have simple function , lets say function Person(){} 
You could do Foo.prototype = {age: 6}; , it is going to work absolutely fine 
just add the constructor

Comment: Normally if see libraries they basically use 
Foo.protytype.someFunction = function (){} and donot assign a new object to the protoype